# create new column in dataframe on nested dict

Tags: python, dataframe, flatten

The original file is json data.I just convert json data to dataframe.There are two columns in dataset.One is `desp`,another is `info`.`info` has nest dict.

```html
desp       info
this is a {'user_id':12349578,'group':'a','request':False}
looks nice{'user_id':23789094,'group':'b','request':False}
sunny day {'user_id':12398467,'group':'c','request':False}
```

I want to get a new dataframe which can only include `desp`and`user_id` as column name.
So the expected dataframe will like this:

```html
desp           user_id
this is a      12349578
looks nice     23789094
sunny day      12398467
```

I think I need to use `concat` and `join` to rebuild dataframe,but still have some trouble.

Comment: This isn't a valid dataframe nor python. Additionally, if you would execute this in python (given the fact that you'd set 0001234567 and 0007654321 in '' first), group A would be replaced by group B since you use your dictionary-key twice.. Please provide a valid example

Comment: Can you modify the question with a valid input dataframe?

Comment: sorry for confusion.I just revised the dataset to look like format.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
#if info is a string, then you can yaml to convert to dictionary
import yaml
df = df.applymap(yaml.load)
```

Then use `transform`:

```
df['user'] = df['info'].transform(lambda x: x['user_id'])
```

Output:

```
         desp                                               info      user
0   this is a  {'user_id': 12349578, 'group': 'a', 'request':...  12349578
1  looks nice  {'user_id': 23789094, 'group': 'b', 'request':...  23789094
2   sunny day  {'user_id': 12398467, 'group': 'c', 'request':...  12398467
```